# Speeding up st_buffer on many line segments

Tags: r, r-sf

I am buffering around a road network with many small line segments and it takes a long time. When I tried using the profiler to see what was making it take so long most of the time is occupied by ".Call". So I am wondering what is happening in the .Call section and is there anything I could do to speed up this process?

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(sf)
my_linestring_sfc <- st_sfc(
  st_linestring(matrix(c(-10, -10, -1, -1, 0, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)), 
  st_linestring(matrix(c(10, -10, 1, -1, 0, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)), 
  st_linestring(matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
)

line_lst <- map(1:10000 *5, ~my_linestring_sfc + .x)

lins <- do.call(c, line_lst)

profvis::profvis({st_buffer(lins, 100)})
```

And what the profile flame graph looks like for me:
[image: flamegraph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `.Call` refers to an internal call within `st_buffer`. It probably calls `c` libraries or other optimized compiled code. It is unlikely that you will be able to easily speed this up. Simplifying your lines might be one way to speed up without hardly degrading the quality of you outcome, this can be done with `st_simplify`.

A bit more detail if you look at the code of `sf:::st_buffer.sfc` you see it calls: `sf:::CPL_geos_op` which in it self is basically a wrapper for a call to a internal compiled function.

Comment: Excellent! cut the time by 1/4. If others need guidance on the dTolerance parameter in st_simplify see this [Q](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11910/meaning-of-simplifys-tolerance-parameter)